# How to drop in a ball into a box when a text is accepted (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a simple website which has 3 boxes:
When I click on any box, a javascript prompt will open and will ask for a text. After that text is accepted, a ball should be dropped into the box. How can I do that?
This is the code which I used:

```
<html>
<head id = "hd">
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <!--<meta name = "format-detection" -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // function init () {

        // }


        function myFunction() {
            var person = prompt("Please enter your thoughts");
        }   


    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    </div>
        <!--<p id = "demo"></p>-->
        <div class="fixed-size-square" onclick="myFunction()">
            <span>Past Thoughts</span>
        </div>

        <div class="size-square" onclick="myFunction()">
            <span>Present Thoughts</span>
        </div>

        <div class="square"onclick="myFunction()">
            <span>Future Thoughts</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><button>I've no thoughts</button></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 70;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        context.stroke();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think you should follow a few tutorials on html canvas first. your task is easy as soon as you understand how to actually animate stuff on a canvas. besides, why not just do it in html&javascript? if a ball is all you want, you dont need to draw it on a canvas, just use a round-cornered square div...

Comment: Okay, Thank you. Let me implement it. I'll be back with results

Answer (score -2):

This code might help.

```
<html>
<head id = "hd">
    <meta charset = "utf-8" />
    <!--<meta name = "format-detection" -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
    <script src="modernizr.custom.86871.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // function canvas-support () {
        //  return modernizr.canvas;
        // }


        function myFunction() {
            var thought = prompt("Please enter your thoughts"); 
   //          if (document.getElementById('fixed-size-square').clicked == true){
   //           var thought = prompt("Please enter your thoughts"); 
   //           }
   //           else if (document.getElementById('size-square').clicked == true) {
   //               var thought1 = prompt("Please enter your thoughts");
            // }
            // else if (document.getElementById('square').clicked == true) {
            //  var thought2 = prompt("Please enter your thoughts");        
            // }
            // else{
            //  return;
            // }
            var thought = document.getElementById('fixed-size-square');
            var thought1 = document.getElementById('size-square');
            var thought2 = document.getElementById('size');

            if (thought) {
                var x = 50;
                var y = 150;
                var speed = 5; 
                function gameLoop(x,y,speed) {
                    y += speed;
                    x += speed;
                }
            }
        }   


    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    </div>
        <!--<p id = "demo"></p>-->

        <div class="fixed-size-square" onclick="myFunction()">
            <span>Past Thoughts</span>  

        </div>

        <div class="size-square" onclick="myFunction()">
            <span>Present Thoughts</span>
        </div>

        <div class="square"onclick="myFunction()">
            <span>Future Thoughts</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>I've no thoughts</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        var radius = 20;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'red';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        // context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        // context.stroke();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```